# RxJs запросы в цикле

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

У меня есть список параметров и для каждого параметра отправляется запрос на сервер. Количество параметров может быть разным, поэтому запросы отправляются в цикле. Вопрос, как мне отправить запросы по всем параметрам, дождаться ответа от всех запросов и продолжить выполнение программы. Для этого нужно использовать Rx Js.

```
    parameter.dependParams.forEach(function (element) {

    let par = pars.find(p => locator(p, element));
    if (par) {

      par.loading = true;

      service.getValues(element, pars, action.action, action.actionScheme).subscribe(
        data => {
          par.values = data;
          par.loading = false;
          console.log("Значения получены");
        },
        error => {
          this.error = error.error.message || error.statusText;
          par.loading = false;
          this.showError();
        }
      );}}
```

Comment: В чем, собственно, вопрос?

Comment: Исправил вопрос

Comment: ты хочешь отправить сразу все запросы и дождаться ответ всех или запрашивать по одному дожидаться и запрашивать следующий?

Comment: Посмотри в сторону [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)

Comment: Отправить сразу все запросы и дождаться ответ от всех них